# How to replace values of a columns given a specific scheme?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the column `log_index` that could look like this

```
log_index
27
27
27
27
28
28
29
29
29
27
27
27
28
28
28
```

Now, I want to start at `1` so that the column is changed as follows

```
log_index
27 -> 1
27 -> 1
27 -> 1
27 -> 1
28 -> 2
28 -> 2
29 -> 3
29 -> 3
29 -> 3
27 -> 4
27 -> 4
27 -> 4
28 -> 5
28 -> 5
28 -> 5
```

how could I achieve this the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of the boolean Series comparing one value to the previous (with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)):

```
df['new'] = df['log_index'].ne(df['log_index'].shift()).cumsum()
```

*NB. assign back to `df['log_index']` to modify in place.*

Output:

```
    log_index  new
0          27    1
1          27    1
2          27    1
3          27    1
4          28    2
5          28    2
6          29    3
7          29    3
8          29    3
9          27    4
10         27    4
11         27    4
12         28    5
13         28    5
14         28    5
```